# Row limit is not working in code , but working fine in the query builder

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

I want to limit my fetched record as 10 row per page for this I am using the following query, which is working fine in Query builder, but not in my code :

```
<Where>
  <Geq>
     <FieldRef Name='ID' />
     <Value Type='Counter'>120</Value>
  </Geq>
</Where>
<QueryOptions>
  <RowLimit>5</RowLimit>
</QueryOptions>
```

Can you please guide me where is the error ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use RowLimit Property and don't write RowLimit in CAML itself as described below:

```
SPQuery oQuery = new SPQuery();
oQuery.RowLimit = 10;
oQuery.Query = "<OrderBy Override=\"TRUE\">" +
               "<FieldRef Name=\"FileLeafRef\" /></OrderBy>";
```

Please change the CAML Query according to your needs.

Comment: Please mark it as answer if it solves your query.

Comment: Thanks Varun, but what was the problem. It will help me in my future development.

Comment: The <RowLimit> tag is in the schema definition of a view (direct child of <View>) and therefore cannot be nested inside a <Query> tag.